# Permissions to remove all files in subdirectory

Tags: permissions, rm, shared-folders

I have a folder **myfolder** with lots of files and directories as follows:

```
-rwxrwx--x user1  user1   .
-rwxrwx--x root   root    ..
-rw-rw---- user1  user1   file1
-rw-rw---- user1  user1   file2
-rwxrwx--x user1  user1   dir1
```

I'd like to have a user: **master** who is able to remove all the files and folders. Be able to do:

```
rm -fr myfolder/*
```

Doing the following does not solve the problem:

```
chown user1:master myfolder
```

Because the user don't have write permissions in the subfolders. The subfolders are written by **user1** randomly.

I can't change the permissions / owners of those files in a one time operation. If I do that user1 won't be able to create/edit files anymore.

What do you recommend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to use ACLs, i.e., something like `setfacl -R -m u:master:rwX  -m d:u:master:rwX ./myfolder`, where especially the second part `d:u:master:rwX` is relevant here since it means that any new files created in the `myfolder` directory will get `rwX` permissions for the user `master`.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, lets do this so...

Create special group.

```
user1:~$ sudo groupadd test
```

Make `user1` and `master` members

```
user1:~$ sudo usermod -a -G test user1
user1:~$ sudo usermod -a -G test master
```

Change `myfolder` dir's group and permissions recursively

```
user1:~$ chown -R user1:test myfolder
user1:~$ chmod -R 774 myfolder
```

Then you could `remove` all `myfolder` content as you want.

**The recursive option allows user master to also modify myfolder's content, if you only want to rm files, with the simple read-write permissions to the dir you have**

Comment: this wouldn't work since it's a one time operation. Any other proposal ?

Comment: @JordiP.S. then give `w` permission to `other's` section to the main dir

Comment: i just want master to be able to do so, not others